# React: Include new prop to the Child Component in Higher Order Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

This is the Higher-Order Component class

`token` is the `prop` which I want to include

```
   import React from "react";
    
    export function requireAuthentication(Component) {
        return class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {
    

            isAuthenticated() {
                return this.props.isAuthenticated;
            }

            render() {;
    
                return (
                    <div>
                        { this.isAuthenticated === true ? <Component token={token} {...this.props} /> }
                    </div>
                );
            }
        };
    }
    
    export default requireAuthentication;
```

When I access the `props` of the `Component`, I get `props.token` as `undefined`? Is there any way to pass new props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to get the `token` to the component if the component has another prop called `isAuthenticated`. You can do it like below.

```
import React from "react";

export function requireAuthentication(Component) {
  return class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {
    isAuthenticated() {
      return this.props.isAuthenticated;
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.isAuthenticated === true ? (
            <Component
              token={"this_token_is_retrieved_by_requireAuthentication"}
              {...this.props}
            />
          ) : (
            <Component {...this.props} />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
}

const MyComp = requireAuthentication(({ token }) => {
  return <div>token: {token}</div>;
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComp isAuthenticated={true} />
      <MyComp isAuthenticated={false} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-frog-zn07r?file=/src/App.js)